# Why does my counter for number of form submissions in a page not work(flask)

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
  a = 0
  w = 0
  timer = 0
  with open("data.json") as datafile:
    data = json.load(datafile)
  if request.method == "POST":
    data["weekly calories"] = int(data["weekly calories"]) +int(data["daily calories"])
    data["total steps"] = int(data["total steps"]) +int(data["daily steps"])
    timer += 1
    if data["daily sleep"] == data["target sleep"]:
        a += 1
        data["streak"] = a
    if timer == 7:
        w += 1
        string = "week " + str(w) + " Calories"
        data[string] = data["weekly Calories"]
        data["weekly Calories"] = 0
    data["daily sleep"] = 0
    data["daily steps"] = 0
    data["daily calories"] = 0
  with open("data.json", "w") as datafile:
    json.dump(data, datafile)
  return render_template("login.html", data = data)
```

This is my code. Although it does update the daily details in the data.json file and the total values, for those that require +=1 like the streak or the timer it does not update. Is there a reason for this? How can i make it so the timer and a increases everytime the conditions are met upon submission?

Comment: When this route is called, `timer` is set to `0`. If it's a `POST`-request, the timer is set to `1`. On a new request, you start with setting `timer` to `0` again.

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: You would need to store the value of `timer`, `a` and `w` in a file or database and then read it from there